# Plot xtick label with half hour frequency

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want the X label is like:

```
00:00    00:30    01:00    01:30    02:00 ...... 23:30
```

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import random

data = [random.random() for i in range(48)]
times = pd.date_range('16-09-2017', periods=48, freq='30MIN')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.plot(times, data)

xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

plt.show()
```

But my X-Label looks like this:

[image: x-axis image]

Whats the problem? 
I have 48 values, each value represents a value for a half hour of a day

Comment: How many x-ticks do you want? Plotting all 48 x-values would make the x-axis labelling very crowded.

Comment: It is possible to plot all 48 values, but the size of plot needs to increase to make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
As my answer was already accepted but didn't work correctly, I added simplified solutions for matplotlib and pandas

The key is to set `x-ticks` parameter correctly

In your case it could look like this:

```
data = [random.random() for i in range(48)]
times = pd.date_range('16-09-2017', periods=48, freq='30MIN')
```

In both cases, you want to use only hours and minutes:

`hour_minutes = times.strftime('%H:%M')`

**1. Matplotlib solution**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.plot(range(len(data)),data)
# .plot(times, data)
plt.xticks(range(len(hour_minutes)), hour_minutes, size='small',
           rotation=45, horizontalalignment='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]

**2. Pandas solution**

```
# create dataframe from arrays (not neccessary, but nice)
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': data,
                      'hour_minutes': hour_minutes})

# specify size of plot
value_plot = df.plot(figsize=(12,5), title='Value by Half-hours')
# first set number of ticks
value_plot.set_xticks(df.index)
# and label them after
value_plot.set_xticklabels(df.hour_minutes, rotation=45, size='small')

# get the plot figure and save it
fig = value_plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig('value_plot.png')
```

[image]

But I also like the alternative method that is proposed here :)

Comment: Thank you. That works, but looks horrible. :) Question is answered, i'll stay with the other x-Label

Comment: If you want to make it look nicer, you need to increase resolution of the output when saving.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `MinuteLocator` and explicitly set it for every 0 and 30 minutes.

```
minlocator = mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=[0,30]) 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(minlocator)
```

And to clean it up - remove extraneous tick marks and fill out the empty space.

```
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(xticks[2:-2]);
hh = pd.Timedelta('30min')
ax.set_xlim(times[0] - hh, times[-1] + hh)
```

[image]

Comment: I like your solution, but the key here is to change figure size, so the x-axis will be readable.

Comment: Its easy to change the figure size, just do it when in yourcall to `plt.subplots`. Like this: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(14,6))`